# Bourne Shell Programming: find smallest/largest number in list

Tags: shell, search

I'm trying to write a shell program that, given an unsorted list of numbers (one per line, any sign, any size), returns the largest number given one argument or returns the smallest number given another argument. That is, if I type "myProgram 1 list", it outputs the largest number, but if I type "myProgram 0 list", it outputs the smallest number.

I think I know how to determine which number to output (switch case with the first argument?) but I have no idea how to go about finding the largest/smallest number in the list. Is there some simple way to go about finding this number? Could anyone give me a few tips? Thanks.

Comment: Is it ok to use some tool like `sort` or should it be strictly sh?

Comment: There's no mention of `sort` in the question, so I'm assuming it should strictly be sh.

Comment: In the question? As in this is homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't want to spoil all the fun, do we? You didn't ask for a solution, you just asked for tips. So here we go:

1. Set `min=""`
2. Read the file line by line

   1. Compare the obtained value `x` to `min` (What if `min` is empty?)
   2. If it is smaller, set `min=x`
3. Print `min`

All you have to do is translate this to sh, and also the opposite for `max`.

There may be easier ways, but this is the simplest pure-sh algorithm I can think of.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I think I know exactly what to do now. (and thanks for not spoiling the fun, of course!)